# Regular expression for 'dd/dd/dd' in search query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am working on a small application where my table has a column in which I have to find all records having value into this format `'dd/dd/dd'` where `d` is the number(1-9).

For example, I want to find data having value into this format `'18/32/23'`.

So I want to know, what will be the regular expression for this format?

Note: this is a not a date format. I am using MySQL.

Comment: What about the possible values in this column?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this?

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE YOUR_COLUMN_NAME REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}$';
```

Answer (score 0):

> All records *having value* into this format 'dd/dd/dd' where d is *the number(1-9)*.

If I understand it well, you want all records that a field like `txt` have or contains a part in your special format - numbers from 1 to 9: [1-9][1-9]/[1-9][1-9]/[1-9][1-9] -:

```
select *
from t
where `txt` regexp '[^0-9][1-9]{2}\/[1-9]{2}\/[1-9]{2}[^0-9]';
```

[**[ SQL Fiddle Demo ]**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87a0e1/4)

---

For exact match use this query instead

```
select *
from t
where `txt` regexp '^[1-9]{2}\/[1-9]{2}\/[1-9]{2}$';
```

[**[ SQL Fiddle Demo ]**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a686/1)

Regex explanation:

```
^            from start of statement
[1-9]{2}     1-9 two times
\/           / character
[1-9]{2}     1-9 two times
\/           / character
[1-9]{2}     1-9 two times
$            end of statement
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying your solution but it gives nothing to me. SELECT id, value FROM `tbl_registration` WHERE value REGEXP '[^1-9][1-9]{2}\/[1-9]{2}\/[1-9]{2}[^1-9]'. I want record only having this type data. I mean exact match

Comment: @Dhirender I edit my answer to cover exact match ;).